# How to pass page size, filters and sort parameters to back- end in Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to use Kendo UI grid with remote data source, but cannot understand how to pass page size, filters and sort parameters to the ASP.Net aspx page that return a json string for grid's data source. Telerik's documentation on Kendo UI is bad because they have no examples on using server-side technologies with Kendo UI. If someone knows this please let me know?

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "json",
                        transport: {
                            read: "GetProducts.aspx"
                        },
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                fields: {
                                    ProductId: { type: "number" },
                                    ProductName: { type: "string" },
                                    CategoryName: { type: "string" },
                                    IncludeProduct : { type: "boolean" } 
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        pageSize: 10,
                        serverPaging: true,
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        serverSorting: true                             
                    },
```

In GetProducts.aspx page, I create a json string in page load event and send it back to browser. **I am using ASP.Net Webforms.**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The parameters are passed automatically in the server request. You need to look at the requests being made (ie Firebug addon for FireFox) to see them all but some of them are skip, take, filter[logic],sort[i][dir], sort[i][field] etc.

If your page number is 3 and your page size is 100 then the skip value passed would be 200 and the take would be 100.

To modify these to pass under different names you would need to use the parameterMap Kendo provides but I don't have experience with that.

I don't have familiarity with ASP.Net Web Forms to know for sure but I wrote this after a basic google search so you can get the basic idea for pulling the parameter.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
   string skip = Request.QueryString["skip"];
 }
```

Comment: What if a static PageMethod was being called, then it seems these parameters do not get passed?

Comment: The implementation on handling a request cannot affect the actual client side request as it is unaware of how the server will handle it. Can you add some snippet of code on your implementation to handle the request?

Comment: hi - I have a page method with a no parameters being passed.  [WebMethod]
    public static FinalData GetProductsData( )
    {
        HttpRequest request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request; ...}